# Qt loop through QHash<QString,QString> to return it's key-value pairs

Tags: c++, qt, loops, collections

I'm trying to loop through a QHash using foreach and get each pair in the QHash and then get the keys and values of those so I can append them to a string.

Here's what I have

```
QString Packet::Serialize() {
    QString sBuilder = Command.toUpper() + " ";

    foreach(QMap<QString,QString> pair, Attributes) {
        sBuilder.append(pair); // i know this isn't right because I couldn't
                               // finish the statement 
    }
}
```

The variable `Attributes` is the QHash.

Also, I realize the code is probably 100% wrong because I'm converting it from C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to append each key/value pair to a string?  Something like this would work:

```
QStringList data;
foreach(const QString &key, Attributes.keys())
    data << key << Attributes.value(key);
sBuilder += data.join(" ");
```

Comment: Won't there be temporary memory allocated for `Attributes.keys()` ?